# How can I restore my wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, security, wallet-recovery, backup

I just purchased a new laptop and I want to decommission my old one.  I have a back-up of my wallet.dat file copied to my new PC.  What do I need to do to restore it to my Bitcoin (Windows) client?  Please note, this is a wallet.dat file that is about 6 months old and I haven't loaded it in at least four months.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not, contingent on the original version of the client that created the file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to put the old wallet.dat in your bitcoin data directory.

**The default for Windows is:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin (XP)

C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin (Vista and 7)
```

Then run the bitcoin client with the `-rescan` option.

Alternatively you can run the bitcoin client with the `-datadir=<location of backup wallet.dat>` as well as the `-rescan` option if you do not want to move/backup the new wallet.dat.

**The default for Mac OS X is:**

```
~/Library/Application\Support\Bitcoin
```

**The default for Linux is:**

```
~/.bitcoin
```

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu too, but the wallet file was located at `~/.bitcoin`

Comment: And on OS X in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/

Comment: Note that since 0.3.21 it is not necessary anymore to specify -rescan when moving a wallet file to a new installation.

Comment: That requires that you wipe out the other wallet. How can you merge the two?