# Wallet balance zero after restoring wallet.dat

Tags: wallet, balance, wallet-recovery

I recently restored my wallet.dat file from another machine. The wallet.dat came from a Linux machine (debian), and was restored to a Windows bitcoin install.

After restoring I can see the correct bitcoin address, but the balance is 0 BTC. The client is still downloading the block-chain (152,000 blocks at time of writing).

When will the balance show? It should have a balance of 0.66 BTC.

The wallet was restored using the answer from this question: [How can I restore my wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-can-i-restore-a-wallet-dat-file)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The balance will return as soon as the client catches up with the network.