# Bitcoin-qt Wallet empty

Tags: bitcoin-core, balance

I just reinstalled Bitcoin-qt and exchanged the new wallet.dat file with my old one. The Address for receiving coins is shown correctly in Bitcoin-qt but the balance is 0.00 BTC. The Block chain is up-to-date and if I check the Address with Blockexplorer it says my Bitcoins are still on this Account. Why is the Balance 0 BTC in Bitcoin-qt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I restore my wallet?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-can-i-restore-my-wallet)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:  start bitcoin-qt with the command line switch "-rescan".  That should re-download all transactions, including those in and out of your wallet.

I can't guarantee this will work, but I had to do this when I upgraded to the newest version of Bitcoin-qt after a long time of not updating.