# How can I restore my dogecoin wallet (android client)

Tags: wallet, security, backup, dogecoin, android

How can I restore my dogecoin wallet backup? It was created by the dogecoin android client and lives in my Google Drive account.

[This question already exists](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-can-i-restore-my-wallet), but no answer is given for Android (and dogecoin *might* be different, I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just hit the option softkey and a menu popped up. Then I tapped "Back up Keys" then tapped "Restore private keys".

[image: http://i.imgur.com/VzQ6V5q.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt5v5.png]