# Will reinstalling bitcoin core give me access to the previous wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

If I reinstall Bitcoin Core, will my previous bitcoin wallet still be accessible or will I get a new wallet? The previous wallet backup became corrupted. Will reinstalling give me back my old wallet or is my wallet lost forever? I don't have a wallet backup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restore my wallet?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-can-i-restore-my-wallet)

Comment: You can import your previous wallet into the new installation, but if it is corrupted it won't work any better than it did in the original installation.  Reinstalling is not the solution here.  If you can't extract your private keys from your wallet file, or find a backup, then your coins are gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear that your wallet got corrupted, hopefully you did not have too much value in there.
I'm afraid that if your wallet.dat file got corrupted and you don't have a backup there is not much you can do.
Back up the wallet.dat file and see if you can find tools to help you fix it.
Reinstalling core will not do much to help you restore a corrupted wallet file.
Can you open the old wallet at all?  Perhaps you can export the private keys that are in it?

Comment: If you have the wallet address you can always try moving it through www.coinbase.com to verify that the wallet itself is intact.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The old wallet can't be opened at all and BitCoin Core had been previously uninstalled. There wasn't much in there, but I was just wondering. I had used Recuva to get the wallet.dat files so that's probably why.