# (Bitcoin Core, recovering my wallet) problem finding the address I sent coins to in Bitcoin Core 0.11.2

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

Im trying to find my Address I sent my Bitcoins to but I do not know how to get into my wallet and since it is quite some time ago, I do not remember from where I sent it.

While trying to open Bitcoin Core on my Mac theres a popup saying that its unable to connect to port 8333 but the program closes afterwards.

Since there is a problem with opening the port I want to transfer the coins to an electrum address. For that I need my seed and the Bitcoin Address I sent my coins to. Is there a way to find it without opening port 8333 and synchronising the blockchain?

Will it be safe to deinstall it and try to boot it again?

Any ideas, suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you used the bitcoin-core wallet, you should back up your `wallet.dat` usually stored on a mac in `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat`. This contains your private keys. Then see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/325/60443 for how to restore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that I can not open my wallet. It says that the port 8333 is closed and I can not go to the folder with my receiving addresses nor to the Command Line for Bitcoin Core.

Comment: I want to get my private key to export it but I dont know how to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to backup your `wallet.dat` file. Then, since your installation is from a while ago, I would recommend reinstalling bitcoin, and then importing your `wallet.dat`.

### Backup wallet.dat

To copy your `wallet.dat` on a Mac:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then type terminal

In terminal type:

`cp ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat ~/Desktop`

I would recommend also backing up a copy to another computer or disk drive.

### Install Bitcoin-core

Download and open `.dmg` file from [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/download), and follow installation instructions.

### Restore wallet.dat

To copy your `wallet.dat` back on a Mac:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then type terminal

In terminal type:

`cp ~/Desktop/wallet.dat ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`

Then you can export your key to whatever wallet you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your answer. This will surely help alot! But for now I only want to get into my wallet or to the help button. Even when I uninstall the previous version and run the new .dmg file .... the same issue as before. It tries to connect to 8333, cant find it and shuts down. No way to get my priv key through "help"--> "command". It simply wont let me into my wallet.

Comment: is port 8333 behind a firewall? Have you tried a different network?

Comment: I tried other ports but something blocks it. I have tried to put Bitcoin core on the whitelist of my firewall. Still doesnt change.

Comment: You could try a website like this to see if port 8333 blocked: https://www.lurkmore.com/mining/port8333/ . If so, you need to forward port 8333 on your router to the ip of the computer you're using.

Comment: I have tried setting up the port forwarding quite some times. Have set an static IP, Forwarded Ports to that IP and checked other ports as well. Seems not to work for me. In an other forum I heard that its possible to put the wallet.dat file from this computer to an other. There I can implement the old key to the bitcoin folder and would be able to handle my wallet without needing to synch my wallet. Maybe I will go for that option.

Comment: That's pretty much what the answer above describes.

Comment: Yes indeed! thanks a lot for that! Just was not sure whether there would be an other option. But this seems to work out fine for me. Going to check out the next days and will tell if it worked.